# How I can change wp-login link?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, authentication

I installed a Wordpress site, newest version. In standard version Wordpress login page is domain.com/wp-admin, but my client wants to WP login address was:

> domain.com/b-login

How can I change this? Plugin "Hide Login+" doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 steps to this. First, a change to your `.htaccess` file and then step to is to addi a function to your `functions.php` file.

### Step 1

the original `.htaccess` looks like this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

so, after

```
RewriteBase /
```

add a new rule, like this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^b-login$ wp-login.php
```

Now you can access the login page using these 2 urls (`/b-login` and `/wp-login.php`).

Next we need to redirect the `wp-login.php` page.

### Step 2

Add this code to redirect to your `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter('site_url',  'wplogin_filter', 10, 3);
function wplogin_filter( $url, $path, $orig_scheme )
{
 $old  = array( "/(wp-login\.php)/");
 $new  = array( "b-login");
 return preg_replace( $old, $new, $url, 1);
}
```

This should now work completely, also make sure to have a backup ready though just in case.